# NPM `pangea-node-sdk` is not working on typescript nestjs project

Tags: typescript, nestjs

When I try to this `import { PangeaConfig, AuditService, PangeaErrors } from 'pangea-node-sdk';`, it get's imported, but when typescript .ts compile it in .js extension it gives an error of this:

```
const pangea_node_sdk_1 = require("pangea-node-sdk");
                          ^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module
```

I did make changes in tsconfig.json but still it get's failed during compilation in .js file. I've tried to connect to pangea community but still no luck.

Is Anyone using pangea services?? And ever faced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the `pangea-node-sdk` doesn't support CommonJS which is why you're getting this error.

However, there's a workaround you can perform to fix the error:

1. Set `"module": "node16"` in `tsconfig.json`.
2. Set `"type": "module"` in `package.json`.
3. Use `.js` file extensions when doing relative imports. So for example: `import { AppModule } from './app.module';` should be `import { AppModule } from './app.module.js';`.

This workaround converts the Nest.js project into an ESM one to support the `pangea-node-sdk`.

Additionally, [Pangea](https://pangea.cloud/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=pangea-node-sdk-answer) is rolling out CommonJS support soon which should fix this issue without having to perform the workaround!

Comment: I was able to use pangea by using it's AP instead SDK. :)